# How can I hold objects of different types in a collection in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, interface

I want to hold objects of different types in the same collection, but am unable to solve the problem.

```
public class SetupStep
{
   public ObservableCollection</*Picture- or ParameterContaienr*/> Containers {get; set;}
}

public class PictureContainer
{
   public ObservableCollection<Picture> Content {get; set;}
}

public class ParameterContainer
{
   public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Content {get; set;}
}
```

I think that this would be solvable via interfaces and generics, but I have not found a working solution so far.
In the end, the container collection is to be bound to an ItemsSource of a `ScatterView` in WPF, which should display the individual containers with their different contents.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<object>` would work for any item type. Data template resolution and binding to properties of individual items still works, as it's done by reflection.

Comment: It all depends on the question if you need to manipulate the elements of the Containers collection after they were added to the collection, i.e. if you need to set their properties or call their methods. If not, no interfaces or generics are necessary, just store the elements in an `ObservableCollection<object>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make them implement same interface:

```
public interface IContainer
{
    // common properties
}

public class Picture: IContainer
{
   // prop
}

public class Parameter: IContainer
{
   //prop
}

public class SetupStep
{
   public ObservableCollection<IContainer> Containers {get; set;}
}
```

Here how to fill your collection:

```
SetupStep step = new SetupStep();
step.Containers = new ObservableCollection<IContainer>();

Parameter p = new Parameter();
Picture pic = new Picture();

step.Containers.Add(p);
step.Containers.Add(pic);
```

Comment: Or use the fact that all objects derive from Object

Comment: @DmitryOgurtsov this is probably not a good idea, because you need to cast the objects after that. With your common interface you can use common properties and methods. If you use Object you need to cast your objects to Picture or Parameter to use them properly. This will lead to messy code and it was one of the main reasons that ArrayList(stores objects) became obsolete.

Comment: @mybirthname From the question it seems that "the container collection is to be bound to an ItemsSource of a ScatterView in WPF, which should display the individual containers with their different contents", i.e. view only, no manipulation.

Comment: @mybirthname Correct, if there is a common interface (and probably there is)

Comment: I have progressed with your solution. Each container has its own content. I have included in the interface icontainer the property "ObservableCollection <object> Content". So I can first record different contents. Let's see how far I get! Thank you :)

Comment: @Alex you can mark the answer for correct if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use generic to tackle the issue

```
public interface BaseContainer
{
    // common properties
}

public class Picture : BaseContainer
{

}

public class Parameter : BaseContainer
{

}
interface SetupStep<T> where T:BaseContainer
{
    ObservableCollection<T> Containers { get; set; }
}

public class PictureContainer:SetupStep<Picture>
{

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Containers { get; set; }
}

public class ParameterContainer : SetupStep<Parameter>
{
    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Containers { get; set; }
}
```